# How to determine if file uploaded or picked with Google Picker?

Tags: google-drive-api

If I'm uploading a file using Google Picker, is there a way to determine if the file was uploaded or selected from the existing files in the picker?

As far as I can tell, I have to guess based on the file metadata.  If the file for the returned file id was just created in Drive, then it was probably uploaded.  Though this seems questionable in the case of a person uploading a bunch of files or even copy files to their Drive folder if they have Google Drive for Windows installed, then they use the picker to select the file they just uploaded.  If the local time and metadata times were not synced, it'd be very hard to tell if the file was created in the last few seconds or a minute ago, if the local time was off.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Document object passed to the callback (or rather any of the Document objects in the array passed back) will have an isNew property set to true, if the file was uploaded via the picker.  If it was not uploaded via the picker, the property does not exist.

This is not documented.